# Play audio from float arrays iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiofile

I have 2 float arrays one representing the left channel values and the other representing the right channel values. How can I create and play music from these two arrays?(Sample Rate = 44100) TIA

Comment: Elaborate your answer with your code.

Comment: There is not much of code.    var leftChannelData:[Float] = [....(values).......]                  var rightChannelData:[Float] = [....(values).......]                   That is it. I want to play music using these values

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/ToneGenerator1.0-Swift/blob/master/ToneGenerator/AVTonePlayerUnit.swift) is an example of what you want to do. You just have to change it to use 2 channels instead of 1 and change the fillBuffer function to fill the buffers using your values.