# How to mix different Audio Files to one file

Tags: swift, xcode, audio

I know there are many other problems here on stackoverflow like my problem. But I didn't found the right one. I want to simulate an tabletennis rally in different playback durations. I will record one sound  (e.g. in mp3) when I hit the Ball (A), when the ball hits the table on my side (B), the ball hits the table on the other side (C) and the other Player hits the ball (D). So I have 4 different soundfiles in mp3. I think it is much more precise if I generate one mp3 file which contains the different sounds. I think this could be the right way.

1. I create an empty soundfile (mp3) with a length of X seconds.
2. I insert file (D) at position 0. The complete length of the mixed file is the same as before (X sconds).
3. I insert file (B) at position x1. The complete length of the mixed file is the same as before (X sconds).
4. I insert file (A) at position x2. The complete length of the mixed file is the same as before (X sconds).
5. I insert file (C) at position x3. The complete length of the mixed file is the same as before (X sconds).

Now I can play this in a loop. This could be easier as play different sounds every 250 msec.

My questions:

1. Is this the right way?
2. Or is it not a problem to play different sounds every 250 msec?
3. If (1): How can I mix mp3 files? (a link to an actual working example could be helpful)
4. If (2): How can I play sounds exactly at a defined msecond?

Thanks Jens

Comment: I would say the best way to go about it into read all files into separate [float buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537505/ios-how-to-read-an-audio-file-into-a-float-buffer). From there, create a new buffer of the required length. Then, copy the content of the 4 buffers into the correct positions in the main buffer. Your final stage will be the saving the main buffer as an `.mp3` file.

Comment: Of course, that assumes that you need to save the final output to a file. If you just need to assemble and play audio on the fly, then you could simply play out the final [float buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462476/play-audio-from-float-arrays-ios-swift).